# Extract text from string up to ":" colon, if exists?

Tags: php, string

My app stores strings in this way:

```
Yanone+Kaffeesatz:700
PT+Sans+Narrow
PT+Sans+Narrow:regular,bold
...etc
```

I need to transform each of these strings so that the end result is everything to the left of the colon (if there is one).

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What should happen if there isn't a colon? What if there are two colons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`strtok()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php)

```
$sub = strtok($string, ':');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$s = preg_replace('/:.*/', '', $s);
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/PYWOW#view_edit_box)

Comment: Replacing what you don't need with an empty string, seems like an odd way to do it. preg_match seems like a better fit.

Comment: @Evert: Yes it's better... or worse... depending on what the OP wants to do with lines that don't contain a colon. I prefer to just say "different" since we don't actually know what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
list($key, $value) = explode(':', $inputLine, 2);
```

In case you really don't need the value, you can just omit it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

$string = "whatever you want your string to be";

$tok_string = strtok($string, ':');