# javascript or jquery equivalent of PHP's strtok()?

Tags: jquery, regex

Is there a javascript equivalent to PHPs strtok()? In PHP, I'd use

```
$sub = strtok($string, ':');
```

([Thanks to Phil's answer for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829822/extract-text-from-string-up-to-colon-if-exists))

However, I need to do the same in javascript.

I have a select list that contains values like this:

```
<select id="myFonts">
    <option value='Leckerli One'>Leckerli One</option>
    <option value='Lekton:regular,italic,bold'>Lekton (plus italic and bold)</option>
    <option value='OFL Sorts Mill Goudy TT:regular,italic'>OFL Sorts Mill Goudy TT (plus italic)</option>
</select>
```

And in the jQuery change event, I need to extract the "value" field. However, if the value field contains a colon, I need to pull the string contents before the colon and return nothing after it.

For instance, in my example above, I need the values returned:

Leckerli One
Lekton
OFL Sorts Mill Goudy TT

Here's my jQuery currently (does not work properly when value contains the colon and additional properties):

```
$('#myFonts').change
(
    function()
    {
    var myFont = $('#myFonts :selected').val();
    $('#fontPreviewSrc').attr('href','http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family='+myFont);
    $('.fontPreview').attr('style','font-family:'+myFont+';font-style:normal;font-size:2em;padding-top:10px;white-space:nowrap');
    }
);
```

Comment: have you tried `split()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use:

```
$('#myFonts :selected').val().split(':')[0]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a native JavaScript solution that supports multiple chars the same way PHP [strtok()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) does:

```
/**
 * @param   {string}   s      the string to search in
 * @param   {string}   chars  the chars to search for
 * @param   {boolean=} rtl    option to parse from right to left
 * @return  {string}
 * @example tok( 'example.com?q=value#frag', '?#' ); // 'example.com'
 * @example tok( 'example.com?q=value#frag', '?#', true ); // 'frag'
 */
function tok ( s, chars, rtl ) {
    var n, i = chars.length;
    rtl = true === rtl;
    while ( i-- ) {
        n = s.indexOf(chars[i]);
        s = n < 0 ? s : rtl 
            ? s.substr(++n)
            : s.substr(0, n);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) with [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) or [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) was faster than using [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with pop or shift. See [jsperf.com/tok](http://jsperf.com/tok)

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the `split` method.  By limiting the length to 1 you can extract the value before the colon

```
var beforeColon = value.split(':', 1)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get you everything before the colon, if there is one, or the entire value if there isn't:

```
var myFont = $('#myFonts :selected').val().split(':')[0];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/8uWCN/

Answer (score 1):

As mention above use split for single char delimeter.
For multiple chars delimeter I wrote this:

```
function strtok(src, delim){
  delim_escaped = new RegExp('[' + delim.replace(/[\[\]\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|\#\-\{\}\/]/g, "\\$&") + ']', 'g');
  return src.replace(delim_escaped, delim[0]).split(delim[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Relatedly, you may be interested in [these benchmarks](https://jsperf.com/slice-vs-substr-vs-substring-vs-split-vs-regexp/2). Note that the options with `slice`, `substr`, and `substring` work only if you can be sure that the separator exists. If the separator may be absent (as in your first example), use the version with `split` as suggested by other users.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact equivalent to php's `strtok` function in javascript (I was searching for the same), but I noticed that all of the answers here missed a nuance of the strtok function and wanted to point it out.

If all you're looking to do is break up an string based on a single token, then the various methods of splitting and slicing is fine, but strtok does more than just that. It walks a string and remembers where it left off. It's like it's using a pointer behind the scenes.

Consider the following string:

> ullamcorper dignissim non non turpis. Donec sit amet pharetra tortor. Suspendisse tristique luctus %velit, ac maximus tortor ullamcorper et. Vivamus vitae magna a lectus mollis tempus ac commodo orci^. Donec aliquam malesuada massa sed interdum. Curabitur sit amet ex dictum, sollicitudin eros non, rutrum enim.

If you wanted to wrap the text bween the `%` and the `^` in bold tags, how would you do that? You could split, grab indexes, etc, but the `strtok` function will let you walk the string in a more sophisticated way:

```
// assume the `$string` variable holds the big string above
$pre = strtok($string, '%');

$boldme = strtok('^');
$bolded = "<b>$boldme</b>";

$post = strtok("\n");

$newstring = implode("", [$pre, $bolded, $post]);

echo $newstring
```

Now your new string looks like:

> ullamcorper dignissim non non turpis. Donec sit amet pharetra tortor. Suspendisse tristique luctus **velit, ac maximus tortor ullamcorper et. Vivamus vitae magna a lectus mollis tempus ac commodo orci**. Donec aliquam malesuada massa sed interdum. Curabitur sit amet ex dictum, sollicitudin eros non, rutrum enim."

The `strtok` function will allow you to use different tokens at different times to break up a string and because the function acts on the same string after you initialize it you can perform logic between calls to it.

I don't know a php function that will do all of this, but if someone else does I'd love to know ;)

Comment: PHP has a strtok function.  Perhaps your last sentence meant to say "Javascript" instead?