# Count of multiple substrings in JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am receiving a tokenized string from the server in the form of status---delimiter---status where I may have up to 1000 statuses. There are only 6 different possible values for status. I am trying to find a way to search for all 6 at once and that gives me a count of each. I've come up with several less optimum ways of solving the issue but the best I could think of still effectively makes 2 full passes on the string and involves several substeps. I looked at regX .match and capture groups but couldn't seem to find any way to make that work better then one status at a time. I realize the performance difference wont be noticeable but now I just want to know, since in theory this should be doable (though maybe not with JavaScripts regX).

Example
Set of statuses: [red,blue,green,orange,purple,pink]
Delimiter (I can chose this): |
String: red|purple|green|red|blue|orange|purple|blue

Result: [red: 2, blue: 2, green: 1, orange: 1, purple, 2, pink 0]

Comment: why not use var arr=  your_string.split(delimiter) and then go through the array and count them?

Comment: That's my 2 pass solution. Since splitting is one full pass and then the array has to be searched through to place each status in the correct count.

Comment: could you tell your status options and the delimiter?

Comment: Added an example, the delimiter is my choice of a single character.

Comment: Arent the other answers enough? Seem to work

Comment: I'm examining them at the moment, was just trying to provide clarification since it was asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear. This is what I'm assuming you're attempting to do (ie. `---delimiter---` is wrapped in a status):

```
var string = 'status1---delimiter---status1 asdf status1---delimiter---status1 asdf asdf fdsa status3---delimiter---status3 asdf status1---delimiter---status1 fdsa status1---delimiter--- asdf status5---delimiter---status5 status5---delimiter---status5 asdf status6---delimiter---status6 asdffdsa';
var matches = {}, re = /(status1|status2|status3|status4|status5|status6)---delimiter---\1/g, match;
while (match = re.exec(string)) {
    if (!matches.hasOwnProperty(match[1])) {
        matches[match[1]] = 1;
    } else {
        matches[match[1]] += 1;
    }
}
/*
 * matches = {
 *     status1: 3,
 *     status3: 1,
 *     status5: 2,
 *     status6: 1
 * }
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtok` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13696734/2877364) to iterate down the string once, pulling each "token" (status value) in turn, and increment the counts as you go.

Comment: That looks like what I want with some modifications, thank you.