# Is there a javascript equivalent to php's strtok function?

Tags: javascript, php

I was looking for a function in javascript that is an equivalent to php's `strtok` function and found this question/answers:

[javascript or jquery equivalent of PHP's strtok()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841711/javascript-or-jquery-equivalent-of-phps-strtok/53163790)

There are a lot of good splitting options, but none were an actual equivalent to strtok.

I added my input here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53163790/1934903

**From the post:**

I don't know the exact equivalent to php's `strtok` function in javascript (I was searching for the same), but I noticed that all of the answers here missed a nuance of the strtok function and wanted to point it out.

If all you're looking to do is break up an string based on a single token, then the various methods of splitting and slicing is fine, but strtok does more than just that. It walks a string and remembers where it left off. It's like it's using a pointer behind the scenes.

Consider the following string:

> ullamcorper dignissim non non turpis. Donec sit amet pharetra tortor. Suspendisse tristique luctus %velit, ac maximus tortor ullamcorper et. Vivamus vitae magna a lectus mollis tempus ac commodo orci^. Donec aliquam malesuada massa sed interdum. Curabitur sit amet ex dictum, sollicitudin eros non, rutrum enim.

If you wanted to wrap the text bween the `%` and the `^` in bold tags, how would you do that? You could split, grab indexes, etc, but the `strtok` function will let you walk the string in a more sophisticated way:

```
// assume the `$string` variable holds the big string above
$pre = strtok($string, '%');

$boldme = strtok('^');
$bolded = "<b>$boldme</b>";

$post = strtok("\n");

$newstring = implode("", [$pre, $bolded, $post]);

echo $newstring
```

Now your new string looks like:

> ullamcorper dignissim non non turpis. Donec sit amet pharetra tortor. Suspendisse tristique luctus **velit, ac maximus tortor ullamcorper et. Vivamus vitae magna a lectus mollis tempus ac commodo orci**. Donec aliquam malesuada massa sed interdum. Curabitur sit amet ex dictum, sollicitudin eros non, rutrum enim."

The `strtok` function will allow you to use different tokens at different times to break up a string and because the function acts on the same string after you initialize it you can perform logic between calls to it.

---

So, is there an actual equivalent to php's `strtok` or would you have to write this functionality from scratch?

## Update

I think I got people hung up on solving a hypothetically. I'm not worried about how to split a string once and operating on the results, I was asking about an equivalent so that I understand if there is a ready made javascript equivalent of the strtok parsing tool in php.

Yeah, a `strtok` tool isn't the best option for the example I posted, the example is a simple split and replace at one time using multiple delimiters.

but the state tracking ability of `strtok` is advantageous if you're needing to change how you're parsing based on the results of the first part of the parse.

Like in my example I gave two different delimiters, an opening and closing one, but what if you're trying to do more complex parsing where the delimiters you're looking for changes based on the previous parts of the string parsed? Like if you're looking for specific punctuation based on the previous punctuation found (e.g. I just found a semi-colon so now I want to see if the next punctuation is a period or a comma and if it's a comma I want to look for more commas until I hit a period).

Trying to do this with split or regex the code can get really conditional heavy or very cryptic. You can write a class to track the choices and the string state, or you can use a function that already tracks the string state and just worry about the branching logic.

Again, a hypothetical, but I'm trying to point out that I'm not ask about how to split a string or how to replace characters, it's more about if there's an existing function that allows for this kind of built in state tracking or if I'd need to build it from scratch.

It's fine if that doesn't exist and I have to build it myself whenever I want to use it, I was just wondering if someone else had already done it.

Comment: Have you considered just using `String.prototype.split` with a regex for the separator?

Comment: to add to what @fubar said you basically want something like this: mystring.replace(/\%(.*)\^/,"<b>$1</b>")

Comment: Yes split is an option, but it doesn't replicate the state tracking that strtok does. That's the part I was specifically asking about.

Comment: Re: the vote to close because it's a duplicate - The post being referenced as the original is literally the same post that I referenced in my question saying that it didn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a simple class to replicate the functionality.

```js
const Tokenizer = function (string) {
  this.string = string;
  
  this.tokenize = function (separator) {
    const index = this.string.indexOf(separator);
    
    if (index === -1) return false;
    
    const token = this.string.substring(0, index);
    
    this.string = this.string.substring(index + 1);
    
    return token;
  }
}


const string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, modo probatus ut vix, vel ea alia vocent deleniti. Nam in vitae fastidii periculis. Ei est ludus elaboraret. In vim aliquid epicuri, munere pertinacia pro id, ex eos admodum adversarium.';
const t = new Tokenizer(string);


console.log(t.tokenize('.'));
console.log(t.tokenize('.'));
console.log(t.tokenize('.'));
console.log(t.tokenize('.'));
console.log(t.tokenize('.'));
```

Comment: Cool. I figured I'd need to write my own class to accomplish the same functionality. It's good to see an example

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: no. There is no native equivalent. It's also a very risky function in Javascript, as `strtok` has some kind of hidden 'state'. So in both Javascript and PHP you have to make absolutely sure that only 1 section of code is using that function.

This however comes kinda close (and is arguably better):

```
const input = '...'; // your string

const index1 = input.indexOf('%');
const match1 = input.substring(0, index1);

// start looking where match1 ended.
const index2 = input.indexOf('^', index1);
```

All of this is a bit more cumbersome because you need to keep an eye on the `index`. However, these are all good building blocks that would potentially allow you to create a much simpler `strtok`-like function.

Although for your specific use-case, this is far more superior:

```
input.replace(/(%([^\^]+)\^)/g, '<b>$2</b>');
```

Generally when I read a question like yours, it strongly suggests you haven't taken the time to learn regular expressions yet. You really should. They are a super powerful tool, easier than you think and really something every programmer needs to have in their toolbelt.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and you make some good points. I understand regular expression and understand how it's a good option. The point of my question wasn't about how to acomplish this specific task, it was more wondering if there was a function in JavaScript that functions the same way that strtok does. There are risks but definitely some advantages to having a function that tracks state like this. Maybe not the best choice given all options in this case, but still useful. I'm mostly asking to better understand though I can pick from.

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz it's worth pointing out that PHP's `strtok` would _never_ make it into the PHP language today. It's kind of badly designed. Best to ignore it!

Comment: Gotcha. I just learned about strtok today, so I haven't had a chance to fully research it, mostly just considering it's implications and wondering if there are equivalents.